# Retrieve data set from Google Sheets from User Input Unique ID

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to find an easy way to have students enter an ID number and then have it retrieve corresponding data from a google sheet and display their first name, last name, and group assignment.  I've been searching for a sample code etc to make this happen but haven't found anythign that works.

Comment: There is a simplified scenario but no details of underlying assumptions. `students enter an ID number` - where is the number entered? `display their first name, last name, and group assignment.` - where is the information displayed? It's not clear what exactly is your problem.  If you lack script writing skills then that _is_ a problem because _how would you install and manage a script_? I respectfully suggest that you begin by learning [the basics of scripts](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-intro/#0) and submit a question when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get data dialog:

google apps script:

```
function findme(obj) {
  const uid = obj.uid;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();
  const us = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  const idx = us.indexOf(uid);
  if(~idx) {
    //Logger.log(vs[idx]);
    return JSON.stringify(vs[idx]);
  } else {
    return JSON.stringify(["No such id"]);
  }
}

function launchUidDialog() {
  let ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"UID Dialog");
}
```

html: filename: ah2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      console.log("script");
    </script>
    <style> input{margin:2px;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="showme"></div>
     <form>
      <input type="text" id="uidtxt" name="uid" placeholder="Enter UID"/><br><input type="button" value="Submit ID" onClick= "getData(this.parentNode);"/><br><input type="button" value="clear" onClick="clearText();" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function getData(obj) {
        //console.log('obj: %s',JSON.stringify(obj));
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((vs) => {
          //console.log('vs: %s',vs);
          let data = JSON.parse(vs);
          document.getElementById("showme").innerHTML = data.join(",")
        }).findme(obj)
      }
      function clearText() {
        document.getElementById("uidtxt").value='';
        document.getElementById("showme").innerHTML='';
      }  
    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Sheet0 Data File

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uid | first | last | grp |
| 2 | uid1 | first1 | last1 | grp1 |
| 3 | uid2 | first2 | last2 | grp2 |
| 4 | uid3 | first3 | last3 | grp3 |
| 5 | uid4 | first4 | last4 | grp4 |
| 6 | uid5 | first5 | last5 | grp5 |
| 7 | uid6 | first6 | last6 | grp6 |
| 8 | uid7 | first7 | last7 | grp7 |
| 9 | uid8 | first8 | last8 | grp8 |
| 10 | uid9 | first9 | last9 | grp9 |

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was able to make it work for this project. I appreciate your kindness and helpfulness.